# Restarting an Animate animation after variable in Manipulate changes

Tags: plotting, functions, manipulate, animation

I've been trying to restart an animation after variables change from `Manipulate` `PopUpMenus`. My animation takes the form:

```
Animate[expr, {u, umin, umax, du}].
```

I can change `u`, after variations to `Manipulate`, back to an initial value momentarily, but from there `u` jumps back to its previous position (or farther forward) as if its continued running. I would be content with simply restarting the entire animation after changing the `Manipulate` variables.

My code for `Animate[]` is in the following simplified form (I hope to make the `i` slider bar return back to the left and the red dot to begin being plotted at `x=-10` each time the function is changed):

```
gPrev[x_] := Sin[x];
Manipulate[
 Switch[functionNumb, 
   0, g[x_] := Sin[x], 
   1, g[x_] := Cos[x], 
   2, g[x_] := ArcTan[x]], 
 {functionNumb, 0, 2, 1}]

Animate[
 Plot[{g[x]}, {x, -10, 10}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.015], Point@{i, g[i]}}], {i, -10, 10, 1}, 
   DisplayAllSteps -> True, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

Comment: if you post a (formatted) minimal working example you will probably get more/better answers.

Comment: You are welcome, but the code snippet is not working. It is also not exactly minimal:)

Comment: Simplified, working code posted, thanks again.

Comment: It's much better now (+1). Hmm I see where the problem is. Well, let me first give you an improved version of your original code. `Manipulate[
 Animate[Plot[{f[x]}, {x, -10, 10}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.015], Point@{i, f[i]}}], {i, -10, 10, 
   1}, DisplayAllSteps -> True, 
  AnimationRunning -> False], {f, {Sin, Cos, ArcTan}}]`

Comment: So basically the problem is how to reset the i index from the animation? Sorry can't see an obvious way right now.

Comment: Yes, that's the basic problem. I wonder if I could "BREAK" out of the Animate and have it simply restart. Your code snippet was elegant.

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete answer yet:
I've built the functionality using `DynamicModule` and `Animator`, thinking that it will be possible to manually set the index `i` when using the second argument of `Dynamic`. Sadly this only works if the animation is not running. So if the animation is not running `i` is reset correctly. Still, here is the code

**EDIT**
Stealing from Kuba, I'm 80% there. The animation is restarted, but the old animation state is lost. In other words, changing the function will always run the animation.

```
DynamicModule[{i = -10, f = Sin, run = False}, 
 Column@{SetterBar[
    Dynamic[f, (i = -10; run = False; FinishDynamic[]; run = True; 
       Print@i; f = #) &], {Sin, Cos, ArcTan}], 
   Dynamic@Animator[Dynamic[i], {-10, 10, 0.1}, 
     ContinuousAction -> True, AnimationRunning -> run], 
   Dynamic@Plot[{f[x]}, {x, -10, 10}, ImageSize -> Medium, 
     Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.015], Point@{i, f[i]}}]}]
```

Comment: Hmm, there is an `"ResetButton"` under `AppearanceElements`, but I don't know how to call it from code.

Comment: Ahh, You are faster :) I think it works like twhoward99 wanted. +1

Comment: I can't upvote due to my meager reputation, but thank-you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

First I've give one way that fits with the setup in your question, and then I'll give the way I would do it myself, in case that helps.

---

Wrap `Animate` in `Dynamic` and make it track `g`; also keep the `Manipulate` from tracking `g`.  Wrapping `Animate` will make it reset whenever `g` is changed.

```
gPrev[x_] := Sin[x];
Manipulate[
 Switch[functionNumb, 0, g[x_] := Sin[x], 1, g[x_] := Cos[x], 2, 
  g[x_] := ArcTan[x]]; g[x], {functionNumb, 0, 2, 1}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {functionNumb}]

Dynamic@Animate[
  Plot[{g[x]}, {x, -10, 10}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.015], 
     Dynamic@Point@N@{i, g[i]}}], {i, -10, 10, 1}, 
  DisplayAllSteps -> True, AnimationRunning -> False, 
  TrackedSymbols -> {g}]
```

---

Here's a single `Manipulate` that has the same functionality, as I see it, and a more integrated look.

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   i = -10; 
   Animator[Dynamic[i], {-10, 10, 1}, AnimationRunning -> False],
   Plot[function, {x, -10, 10}, 
    Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.015], Dynamic@Point@N@{i, function /. x -> i}},
    ImageSize -> Medium]
   }],
 {function, {Sin[x], Cos[x], 2 ArcTan[x]}},
 {i, -10, 10, 1, ControlType -> None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {function}]
```

[image]

Putting the `Animator` in the control area is a bit trickier, it seems.  It can be done, but my solution is a bit too kludgy to post.

Comment: what exactly it is that makes your second example work (I mean that makes the plot update correctly *and* the animator reset correctly when you change the function)? I ask because if you for example change the `Plot[...]` bit with a more simple Graphics like `Graphics[{Dynamic@Point@{i, i}}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]` it doesn't work anymore, as changing the function doesn't reset `i`. I cannot see the difference between these these two cases: why does one work and the other not?

Comment: @glS It's because plot output depends on `function` but your `Graphics[]` does not. When `function` is changed in your case, it does not trigger an update.